# Compute distance to nearest point xyz coordinates

Tags: r, distance, spatstat

I'm using the spatstat package to compute the nearest distance to it's cooresponding point bases on xyz data. The code works, but i'm getting incorrect answers. See below.

```
ex<- data.frame(long= c(-103.5664,-103.5664,-103.5586),lat= c(32.09539,32.10129,32.10799),elevation= c(5000,5500,5700))
####bounding box 3D
bb <- box3(range(ex$long), range(ex$lat), range(ex$elevation))

# Create a spatial points data frame:
comp_dist.pp3<- spatstat::pp3(ex$long,ex$lat,ex$elevation,bb)

nndist.pp3(comp_dist.pp3,k=1)

[1] 500 200 200
```

The points are more than a mile away so it should be closer to 6800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `spatstat` doesn’t automatically recognize latitude and longitude
coordinates. Your points are interpreted as (x,y,z) coordinates in Euclidean
space, and the three pairwise distances measured by
`sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)` are (very suspiciously) the nice
round numbers 200, 500, and 700. Here is the small change to the original
code to calculate all pairwise distances:

```r
library(spatstat)
ex<- data.frame(long= c(-103.5664,-103.5664,-103.5586),
                lat= c(32.09539,32.10129,32.10799),
                elevation= c(5000,5500,5700))
bb <- box3(range(ex$long), range(ex$lat), range(ex$elevation))
comp_dist.pp3<- spatstat::pp3(ex$long,ex$lat,ex$elevation,bb)
pairdist(comp_dist.pp3)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0  500  700
#> [2,]  500    0  200
#> [3,]  700  200    0
```

You can use `sp::spTransform` or `sf::transform` to convert from spherical
(lon,lat) to planar (x,y) and then you can attach your elevation as z-coordinate
when you define the `pp3` object and things should work.

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: That saved me hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your units. If you look at your longitude values: all around -103, latitude values: all around 32, and elevation values: 5000, 5500, 5700. The dimension that causes the most distance  is the elevation. Since these only differ by 500 and 200, I would not expect distances to be "closer to 6800."

Edit: That is to say, I believe your package is treating your latitudes and longitudes as numeric dimensions on xyz plane, and not as actual latitudes and longitudes!